# Curve_fit for python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

From the below code, I've couple of questions.
1: Why sigmoid graph is not showing over the scatter data ?
2: I am getting the following error
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

```
def sigmoid(x, Beta_1, Beta_2):
         y1 = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Beta_1*(x-Beta_2)))
         return y1
    
beta_1 = 0.10
beta_2 = 1990.0
#logistic function
Y_pred = sigmoid(x_data, beta_1 , beta_2)
#plot initial prediction against datapoints
plt.plot(x_data, Y_pred*15000000000000.)
plt.plot(X, y, 'ro')
    
xdata =x_data/max(x_data)
ydata =y_data/max(y_data)
    
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit( sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
#print the final parameters
print(" beta_1 = %f, beta_2 = %f" % (popt[0], popt[1]))
```

Comment: sorry but there is too much missing information to help, what are `x_data`, `X`, `y`, `y_data`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [example].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.